# Is it possible to return the URL of a website in an external browser(i.e firefox) using C#?

Tags: c#, url, firefox, return

I'm trying to make a program that restricts certain websites by returning the URL of the current page and then doing a search in the string for certain keywords. However, as I'm not accustomed to working with any C# functionality that monitors system activity outside of the C# environment, I do not know if this is even remotely possible. Can anyone shed some light into this?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? How does merely searching for a string "restrict" a website?

Comment: Oh right, I did leave the second component out of the question as it can't be completed without the process above. Once a keyword is found in the URL string, the user is automatically redirected to a blank tab.

PS: This little project isn't meant for use in a professional environment, so any counters to this method won't need to be considered

Comment: So, you want to intercept and edit the HTML of an arbitrary web-page loaded into another (arbitrary) browser process? Generally speaking, that's not possible (unless you implement a proxy service, and lock the machine down to force said processes into using your proxy service).

Comment: I see, even the first part could not be accomplished using C#?

Comment: Use something like HtmlAgilityPack to read-through and modify a HTML document easily enough... if that helps?

Comment: Yes, it does. I checked out the link and this is exactly the kind of functionality I need, thank you!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer to your question - don't forget to accept it!

Answer (score 0):

Following the comment discussion, the HtmlAgilityPack ( http://html-agility-pack.net/ ) can be used to process (even broken and malformatted) HTML documents with ease. You can walk the DOM tree and modify `href=""` attributes, for example, which sounds like half-way towards solving your problem.